# How to remove large data spikes from MySQL Table

Tags: mysql

I have a database that is fed into a graph. For some reason or another every now and then, my PHP script inserts really large spikes into my database...

For example: [image: Screenshot]

As you can see there are random spikes in the graph where the data sometimes goes from 300 upto 3000 then straight back down to 300 again.

What I need is a way to tidy up these tables and remove data where it is massively larger than the previous and next rows.

I've done a bit of google research but can't come up with anything!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put the code of the php script?, maybe the solution is not to remove data... its see why is adding wrong data

Comment: I doubt its the PHP, the reason being is the data is sent from an external program to the php for logging. I'm pretty sure that is the problem.

Comment: Scratch that! I think I found my problem... The Query I'm using retrieves rows at 20 minute intervals, which means if there is a spike that lasts ~20 mins it just shows it as a single spike of users... there has to be some sort of averaging available in SQL!

Comment: then you have to store the time of the retrieved data, not when you retrieve it :P

Comment: The time of the retrieved data is stored in the database too :P

Comment: then is the sql to do the graphic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to remove these "outlier" data points:

You could remove the points that differ from the average by more than N times the standard deviation. For example, if the data were normal-distributed, this would remove roughly the top 2.5%:

```
delete from datapoints where value > (select avg(value)+2*stddev(value) 
                                      from datapoints);
```

Or, you could remove the top 1% of the data directly, leaving the 99th percentile of the data. Finding the percentile point efficiently is a harder problem, but something like this might work:

```
set @rownum = 0;
@percentile = select value from (select value, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum from datapoints) D
              where rownum > (select 0.99*count(value) from datapoints) limit 1;
delete from datapoints where value > @percentile;
```

These approaches delete all data points that are abnormally big in general, with no respect to general trends or cycles in the data. This means that a spike in a valley can go undetected. More advanced algorithms are required to handle these cases. For example you could modify the first approach to remove the outliers based on datapoints in a certain environment:

```
delete from datapoints d2 where value > 
    (select avg(value)+2*stddev(value) 
     from datapoints d1 
     where d1.dt between d2.dt - interval 2 hour 
                     and d2.dt + interval 2 hour);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is delete all rows with values above a certain threshold (here I've used 300), then you can use:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE value > 300;
```

To prevent them from being inserted, you could test your values at insertion time, and only insert rows for those that fall below your threshold.

```
if ($data['value'] < 300) {
    // insert
}
```

Comment: Yea, on a table by table basis sure... but some tables have data values that go from 200 -> 3000 and that is real data. not glitched data.